# How to link against a external jar in Ant?

Tags: android, ant, jar, unity-game-engine

I have a library that uses an external jar. (Unity's stuff) How can I link agains it so the `ant jar` command succeeds? I am quite new to ant so I am kind of lost...

I've tried adding a new property:

```
<property name="unity.androidplayer.jarfile" value="/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/PlaybackEngines/AndroidDevelopmentPlayer/bin/"/>
    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${unity.androidplayer.jarfile}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
    </path>
```

And then adding a "compile" target

```
<target name="compile"
        description="Compiles project's .java files into .class files">
  <javac encoding="ascii" debug="true">
    <src path="${source.dir}" />
    <classpath>
      <pathelement location="${sdk.dir}\platforms\${target}\android.jar"/>
      <pathelement location="${unity.androidplayer.jarfile}"/>
    </classpath>
  </javac>
</target>
```

But it is worse, I get more errors :(

I also tried `<zipgroupfileset dir="${unity.androidplayer.jarfile}" includes="*.jar" excludes="*.config"/>` inside the jar target but nothing changed.

I think I am not adding the `${unity.androidplayer.jarfile}` to the right place.

**Originally my build.xml** looks like this and now I am adding a symbolic to the library into libs/ which I think is not the optimal solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="MyFirstApp" default="help">

<property file="local.properties" />
<property file="ant.properties" />
<property environment="env" />
<condition property="sdk.dir" value="${env.ANDROID_HOME}">
    <isset property="env.ANDROID_HOME" />
</condition>

<loadproperties srcFile="project.properties" />

<fail
        message="sdk.dir is missing. Make sure blah blah..."
        unless="sdk.dir"
/>

<!-- Jar target to make it a library -->
<target name="jar" depends="debug">
  <jar
      destfile="bin/MySuperLibrary.jar"
      basedir="bin/classes"
      includes="net/mycompany/myapp/*"
      />
</target>

<import file="custom_rules.xml" optional="true" />

<import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />
```

Any help is highly appreciated

#### Update

This is the result I get:

```
$ ant jar
Buildfile: /Users/guillermo.enriquez/Documents/github/mycompany/myapp/Android/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.6.2
 [checkenv] Installed at /Users/guillermo.enriquez/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: MyFirstApp
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.3
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for MyFirstApp...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/guillermo.enriquez/Documents/github/mycompany/myapp/Android/bin
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/guillermo.enriquez/Documents/github/mycompany/myapp/Android/bin/res
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/guillermo.enriquez/Documents/github/mycompany/myapp/Android/bin/rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/guillermo.enriquez/Documents/github/mycompany/myapp/Android/bin/rsLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/guillermo.enriquez/Documents/github/mycompany/myapp/Android/gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/guillermo.enriquez/Documents/github/mycompany/myapp/Android/bin/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/guillermo.enriquez/Documents/github/mycompany/myapp/Android/bin/dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for MyFirstApp...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 4 source files to /Users/guillermo.enriquez/Documents/github/mycompany/myapp/Android/bin/classes
    [javac] /Users/guillermo.enriquez/Documents/github/mycompany/myapp/Android/src/com/mycompany/myapp/MySource.java:22: package com.unity3d.player does not exist
    [javac] import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;
    [javac]                          ^
```

Comment: Could you share your `ant jar` commands output?

Comment: @PCoder I just added my results. The library I want seems not to be found

Answer (score 1):

The logs suggests that the problem is related to `javac` not being able to find the libraries in the specified classpath. I would give a try with something like this in my build file.

```
  <path id="android">
    <fileset dir="${sdk.dir}\platforms\${target}">
      <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
  </path>

  <path id="unity">
    <fileset dir="${unity.androidplayer.jarfile}">
      <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
  </path>
```

...

```
  <javac encoding="ascii" debug="true">
    <src path="${source.dir}" />
    <classpath>
        <path refid="android"/>
        <path refid="unity"/>
    </classpath>
  </javac>
```

Comment: you are right, the library is not being found. Doing this lead me to another error. `...mple/myfirstapp/MainActivity.java:16: package R does not exist [javac]  setContentView(R.layout.main);`

Comment: This used to work before using this external library so I believe this is related to the jar included?

Comment: Yeah, that error is probably due to screwed path for the android jar.

Comment: Anyways you can always test whether your path is appropriate using an echo command. `<property name="androidpath" value="${sdk.dir}\platforms\${target}"/>`  and then echo `<echo message=">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>     ${androidpath}"/>`